# How can I create my numbers matching table populate from zero instead of one?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using a numbers matching table, from one upwards. However, I realize I need to start at zero instead. Can't figure it out..

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS util_nums (n integer primary key 
    autoincrement not null);

insert into util_nums(n) select null from (select 0 as n union select 1 
union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 
union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10) a 
    cross join 
(select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 
union select 10) b 
    cross join (select 0 as n union select 1 union select 2 
union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 
union select 8 union select 9 union select 10) c;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's not clear.

Comment: your query is trying to add 1331 `nulls`  into a non-null field, that is also auto-incremented... destined to fail in sql server.. what environment are you working with ?

Comment: Is this MySQL, or some other RDBMS?  If you want to know syntax it's quite important to know...

Comment: I'm using sqlite. I have values 1,2,3,4 etc I need to start from zero.

Comment: posted some possible solutions for sqlite..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite allows you to insert explicit values for the primary key fields:

```
insert into util_nums(n) values (0);
```

to Get a lot more rows insert quickly try this after that..

```
insert into util_nums default values;
insert into util_nums(n) select null from util_nums a, util_nums b, util_nums c, util_nums d;
insert into util_nums(n) select null from util_nums a, util_nums b, util_nums c, util_nums d;
```

Comment: Thanks this answers my question, but its a lot slower, 3 seconds as compared to less than 1 second for my insert query, shame, would have been better to have more values.

Comment: If you do it in a transaction it will be faster ;) Mine has 104,994 numbers in it at the end, yours has 1,331. How many do you NEED is the real question

Answer (score 1):

in sql server it would be easy if you create your table like this

```
CREATE TABLE util_nums (n as int primary key 
    identity(0,1) not null,anotherfieldtoholdthenulls integer);
```

the `identity(0,1)` means start from zero and increment by 1 ..

**update**

try using `UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET seq = -1 WHERE name = 'util_nums'` before starting the insert, and see if it is allowed....

You should also be able to do `INSERT INTO util_nums VALUES(0)`

Answer (score 0):

you can temporarly disable auto increment using

```
 SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
```

But I
 suggest update value to 0 after insert

Comment: I need to use a query, I don't think I ca use SET with sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

["SQLite Autoincrement"](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

The important part seems to be...

```
If no negative ROWID values are inserted explicitly, then automatically
generated ROWID values will always be greater than zero.
```

So?  Create the table, insert a dummy record, with a forced id of -1, and then insert your data.  Deleting the dummy record afterwards as/if necessary.

(Inserting a value with -1 will force the next inserted rwo to have an id of 0, assuming the table was otherwise empty.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're useing SQLite you should probably read this http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html . This caught my eye:

> If the table has never before
>   contained any data, then a ROWID of 1
>   is used.

It doesn't seem to be any way to force autoincrement to start from something other than 1. Also note that it may generate gaps by skipping numbers.

---

This *may* work but I have no means of testing at the moment:
*Add a row with an ID of -1. Then delete it.* It isn't clear from the documentation what happens when you have only negative IDs in the table.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite allows you to specify a value here.

Just insert c.n - 1, from your cartesian product, instead of null, and call it a day.